# Django MySQL - Save Multiple Records together in DB

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7

I am trying to save Multiple records in Django MySQL.
I am able to save each record individually, But it becomes too slow as the array size increases.

Code: [Updated]

```
def MultipleSave(array1, array2, key1, key2):
    insert_list = []
    l = len(array1)
    for i in range(0, l):
        try:
            str1 = array1[i]
            str2 = array2[i]

            try:
                new_record = UserString.objects.filter(original=str1)
                new_record = new_record[0]

                setattr(new_record, key2, str2)
                new_record.save()
            except Exception as e:            
                new_record = UserString(original=str1)

                setattr(new_record, key1, str1)
                setattr(new_record, key2, str2)
                insert_list.append(new_record)

        except Exception as e:
            print ('Exception occured: "%s"' % e)

    if len(insert_list) > 0:
        UserString.objects.bulk_create(insert_list)
```

[Update]: This updated Code now creates all new records at once using bulk_create. But existing records are still updated one at a time.

Is there an alternate way to Save/Update all records at once in the DB rather than for each record ? Or Alternatively, How Can this Code be optimized ?

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem got solved by creating a new list update_list containing all the records which needs to be updated then saving all the records at one go using transaction.atomic()

Updated Code[Working]: (in Django 1.9)

```
def MultipleSave(array1, array2, key1, key2):
    insert_list = []
    update_list = []
    l = len(array1)
    for i in range(0, l):
        try:
            str1 = array1[i]
            str2 = array2[i]

            try:
                new_record = UserString.objects.filter(original=str1)
                new_record = new_record[0]

                setattr(new_record, key2, str2)
                update_list.append(new_record)
            except Exception as e:            
                new_record = UserString(original=str1)

                setattr(new_record, key1, str1)
                setattr(new_record, key2, str2)
                insert_list.append(new_record)

        except Exception as e:
            print ('Exception occured: "%s"' % e)

    if len(insert_list) > 0:
        UserString.objects.bulk_create(insert_list)

    with transaction.atomic():
        for record in update_list:
            record.save()
```

Hope this might be helpful.
Thanks,